# Is Atlasian Bamboo 5.x compatible with Play Framework 2.x

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, bamboo

Can I build and deploy Play Framework 2.x projects with Atlasian Bamboo 5.x?

I see there is a SBT plugin for Bamboo but apparently it doesn't support [bamboo 5](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/203999/is-bamboo-sbt-plugin-compatible-with-bamboo-5-0)  and above.

Will be interested to know if others are having success with Babmoo and Play or if I should stick to Hudson or Jenkins

Answer (score 5):

We are building, testing and deploying several Play 2.x projects successfully using Bamboo. We do it using script tasks. As long as the agents have SBT installed, everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: Hi Lauri, when you say script tasks are you talking about bash/shell scripts caling sbt agents to do the stop/start/clean/run etc?

Comment: Yes, our convetion is that each project has several scripts in scripts/ci folder. Depending on the project there might be several scripts that each have their own purpose. For example one script might setup and run tests and another might send the final package to our package repository to be automatically installed via Puppet. All the script are just bash scripts that you could also run locally. Did this help you?